# MVC3 not finding a View in an Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have one area in my project (for admin).

I want to be able to use a view called Index.cshtml in the Admin area but my app always displays the Index.cshtml view for the main project (which isn't in a seperate area).

If I change the name of the view in the admin area to a name that doesn't exist anywhere else it works fine.

What am I missing? It must be something simple !

**Answer (probably)**

Bit of a mystery but it seems that maybe there was some sort of weird caching problem. I restarted the web server and now it works fine.

thanks to all who responded

Comment: Pass area name explicitly to avoid conflict in the order finding view

Comment: If you set breakpoints for your Index action in the controller in the main project and your Index action in the controller in the Admin area, which is getting hit?

Comment: @Birey - But for the default page, I'd hope to be able to just have http :// myserver.com/Admin and then it whisks me off to Admin/Home/Index.

Comment: @counsellorben - It's the admin controller that gets hit, like I say if the View name doesn't match an existing view name everything works fine.

Comment: What is the namespace for your Admin controller in your area?

Comment: The namespace is ghs.Areas.Admin and the namespace I've added in the areas RegisterArea is ghs.Areas.Admin.Controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question to remove it from the unanswered list.

Bit of a mystery but it seems that maybe there was some sort of weird caching problem. I restarted the web server and now it works fine.

thanks to all who responded